# tag rename request: [repo] -> [repo-tool]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

excerpt for [repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repo) tag says

> Repo is a repository management tool that Android built on top of Git.
>   Repo unifies the many Git repositories when necessary, does the
>   uploads to our revision control system, and automates parts of the
>   Android development workflow. Repo is not meant to replace Git, only
>   to make it easier to work with Git in the context of Android. The repo
>   command is an executable Python script that you can put anywhere in
>   your path.

However, [things tagged with repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repo) are rarely about that. Usually people use the tag whenever they are talking about anything related to git repositories, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34406684/cant-push-to-git-repo-bc-terminal-not-recognizing-correct-username-and-pass) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34215862/how-to-access-github-repository). Sometimes it is used for some other repositories altogether, such as [package repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418980/running-yum-update-and-i-get-this-error).

I think the tag with that naming will continue to attract wrong kind of usage, and instead it should be named to [repo-tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repo-tool). Despite the excerpt, I think [android-repo-tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-repo-tool) would be misleading, since it can and is used in other contexts as well - it can be used in any context when you need a tool using multiple git repositories at once.

(Edit: as per [these instructions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag/197731#197731), I'm now proposing a tag rename instead of discussion and re-worded this as such.)

Comment: No puns in title? :-( .... *git remove [repo]*

Comment: sorry, couldn't come up with one :/

Comment: Indeed it is quite unintuitive, repo-tool sounds great!

Comment: It looks like this lost out to git-repo.

Comment: @JamesMoore I don't think anything has happened one way or the other, unfortunately. git-repo only has 16 questions tagged.