# The [repo] tag and the [git-repo] tag are identical and should be merged

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

[repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repo) and [git-repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-repo) are identical and should be merged.

Related: there's another question asking to rename repo to repo-tool at [tag rename request: [repo] -> [repo-tool]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313182/tag-rename-request-repo-repo-tool) .  Seems like it might be better to keep git-repo.

Answer (score 4):

I disagree with merging the tags together - "git-repo" sounded like a Git repository to me at first reading, so that *alone* would introduce ambiguity, whereas the [git-repo tool](https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo) is ***specific*** to Android development.

At *best* I'd support a renaming of the tag to `android-repo-tool`, but even then...I'd want to defer to Android experts to decide that.

Comment: I think you misunderstand those tags.  _Both_ of them refer to this tool: https://source.android.com/setup/develop/repo.  That tool is a general purpose tool used for managing git repositories - it's definitely not Android specific, although Android does use it.  (It's a horrible, horrible name for a very useful tool, and these tags make a bad situation even worse.)

Comment: @JamesMoore If that's the case, someone should remove the text "in the context of Android" from the [repo] description.